# ¿Existen mas formas de llamar a una vista parcial desde la vista?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp

Existe alguna forma de llamar desde la vista a una `Partial View` como un `Url.Action` o de otra manera? Dado que tengo en mi controlador un metodo que renderiza una vista parcial, pero necesito llamar a ese metodo desde mi vista, por ejemplo `@Html.Partial("Controller", "Action")`

¿De que forma se podrá lograr esto?

Comment: Si "llamas" la vista parcial, el usuario sera redireccionado a la vista parcial. Es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: Como poderse se pueden hacer varias cosas, pero si explicas mejor lo que quieres conseguir o pones algún ejemplo de código igual es más fácil responderte. Por ejemplo puedes insertar la vista parcial dentro de otra usando Html.RenderAction("Nombre_Vista_Parcial"); o la puedes obtener mediante Ajax y añadirla a la página...

Answer (score 0):

La mejor manera en la que lo puedes hacer es llamar `@Html.Action("Action", "Controller")`. Esto hará el llamado directamente sobre el controlador y no solo traerá la vista, como lo hace Html.Partial.

Te recomiendo que esa acción que llames sea de tipo `ChildActionOnly`, para que no pueda ser accedida desde una URL.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public IActionResult Get()
{}
```

Comment: Hola, a que te refieres con que "no solo traerá la vista" traerá algo mas?

Comment: Cuando tu llamas Html.Partial o Html.RenderPartial el no ejecuta ninguna acción en ningún controlador. Solo trae la vista que tu solicitas.
En cambio Html.Action ejecuta una acción y adicionalmente una PartialView